# Google Maps becomes static on Phonegap/Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Im working on a Phonegap project that uses Jquery Mobile as framework.
Using one page layout with div's for pages transitions.

Everything works fine in iOS but on Android the google map becomes a static image !?

Im using this function below to load google maps api dynamically.

```
       var MapLoaded = false; 
       var googleMapsCallback; // Required for Google Maps API to call back when it thinks it is done (vs. when jQuery finishes loading the script file).

(function ($) {
            var googleMapsLoaded = $.Deferred();
            googleMapsCallback = function () {
                googleMapsLoaded.resolve();
            };
            $.extend({
                loadGoogleMaps: function () {
                  if(MapLoaded === false) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=googleMapsCallback&sensor=true",
                        dataType: "script"
                    }).fail(googleMapsLoaded.reject);
                    MapLoaded = true;
                    return googleMapsLoaded.promise();
                  } else {
                    return googleMapsLoaded.promise();
                  }

                }
            });
        }(jQuery));
```

In an other object i'm then creating the map as follows:

```
$.loadGoogleMaps().done(function () {

            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 13,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(Geo.Lat, Geo.Lon),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              disableDefaultUI: true
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                "map" : map,
                "position" : new google.maps.LatLng(Geo.Lat, Geo.Lon),
                "icon" : "img/ph_delivery_car.png"
              });

              for (var i = 0; i < data.neardrivers.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  "map" : map,
                  "position" : new google.maps.LatLng(data.neardrivers[i].Lat, data.neardrivers[i].Lng),
                  "icon" : "img/ph_delivery_car_other.png"
                });
              };

              map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Geo.Lat, Geo.Lon), 16);
              google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

          });
```

Now to the problem, on iOS it works like a charm with markers and all, but on Android the map becomes a static map.

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Pizza24 Dispatch</name>
    <description>
        Pizza24 Dispatch
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        Pizza24 Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <!-- Do not auto hide splash on iOS -->
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <!-- Do not auto hide splash on Android -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="*.google.com"/>
    <access origin="*.googleapis.com"/>
    <access origin="debug.phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />
</widget>
```

Please help!

Comment: Does really no one have any idea or solution?